# TypeError: argument of type 'Message' is not iterable. Discord Python Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I get this error everytime a message is sent ive tried looking for solutions but havent found any here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\super\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 382, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\super\Documents\Discord Bots\First Bot\bot.py", line 27, in on_message
    if bad_word in message:
TypeError: argument of type 'Message' is not iterable
```

Here is the code that isnt working:

```
#Events
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in message:
            await message.send(message.channel, f"{message.author.mention} your message has been censored.")
            await message.delete(message)
```

I do have a list name "bad_words" and there is 1 word in it.

Comment: have you tried thinking through what the error actually means? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message

Comment: Use `message.content` to get the text of the message.

Comment: A lot of this is incorrect syntax. You need `await message.channel.send(f"string")`, and `await message.delete()`

Answer (score 1):

For the Discord module, to get the content of a message, you need to use `message.content`.

Example code:

```
#Events
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    contents = message.content
    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in contents:
            await message.send(message.channel, f"{message.author.mention} your message has been censored.")
            await message.delete(message)
```